# Can't match character value to multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I'm trying to match a character value, "C", to multiple columns in a dataframe. Here's part of the frame:

```
X1 X2

1  F  F
2  C  C
3  D  D
4 A# A#
```

Here's what happens when I try to match the value "C":

```
> "C" %in% frame[, 1]
[1] TRUE
> "C" %in% frame[, 1:2]
[1] FALSE
```

Considering that "C" is in both columns, I can't figure out why it's returning false. Is there a function or operator that can test to see if a value is present in multiple columns? My goal is to create a function that can sum the number of times a character value like "C" is found in specified columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
apply(frame, 2, function(u) "C" %in% u)
```

You can also use `is.element`:

```
apply(frame, 2, function(u) is.element("C",u))
```

Comment: Or `!!colSums(frame == 'C')` .  Also, as per the description, if the OP needs the sum of `C` elements, `colSums(frame=='C')`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `grepl` here, which returns a logical vector. Then you can count the number of occurrences with `sum`.

```
> frame
   X1 X2
 1  F  F
 2  C  C
 3  D  D
 4 A# A#
> grepl('C', frame$X1)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> sum(grepl('C', frame$X1))
 [1] 1
```

and to count the total number of Cs in every column you can use `lapply`
(note: `apply` is better suited for matrices, not data frames which are
lists.)

```
> sum(unlist(lapply(frame, function(col) grepl('C', col))))
 [1] 2
```